# I need to insert a row after the tool is found using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that looks for a specific name on a table. I want that information to be appended to the table.

Thanks

```
Sub findData()
    Dim workflow As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    workflow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c5").Value
    servergri = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c9").Value
    gridf = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c9").Value
    finalrow = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("c100").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 3) = workflow Then
            If Cells(i, 4) = servergri Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
                Range("j42").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            ElseIf Cells(i, 5) = gridf Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
                Range("j42").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

                ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to add a new row under the found row.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

just put this in, but first make sure the correct cell is active.